# The current plot has no coordinates? Tikz/pgf plots

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to graph the function 
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x}}$

using

```
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[axis lines=center]
                    \addplot[domain=0.1:10]{1/(x^(1/2))-((x+1))/(x))^(1/2)};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
```

I am being told all values all being filtered away but this function is well defined on this domain. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had `(` wrong in the formula `((x+1))/(x))` should be `((x+1)/(x))`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
              \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[axis lines=center,
              title={$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x}}$}]
                    \addplot+[domain=0.1:10]{1/(x^(1/2))-((x+1)/(x))^(1/2)};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

To have all the four quadrants, insert the `xmin` `xmax` `ymin` and `ymax` values.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
              \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[axis lines=center,,xmin=-10,xmax=10,ymin=-1,ymax=1,
              title={$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x}}$}]
                    \addplot+[domain=0.1:10]{1/(x^(1/2))-((x+1)/(x))^(1/2)};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Change those suitably as you want.

Comment: If I can tag another question onto this post: How would I set up the axis so that I can the standard four quadrants with this curve sketched on it?

Comment: @az89 Sure, please see the edit.